# Fetch all records based on true flag, or Fetch has_many through if false flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, associations

I am working with a Rails 4 app, which have following associations:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brand_locations
  has_many :locations, through: brand_locations
end

class BrandLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brand_locations
  has_many :brands, through: :brand_locations
end
```

And I am working on a function, on which user can either select a few locations for specific brand, or select all of locations for this brand.

In order to save some insert operations on the join table `brand_locations` ( in case it becomes too large, I have a lot of brands, and a lot of locations, that would be huge records for save these relationship if majority of brands has all of locations.), I plan to add a boolean column called `all_location` in table `brands`,

- when this flag is true, `brand.locations` should return every records in table locations.
- when this flag is false, `brand.locations` should look through `brand_location`, to retrieve all related locations.

How can I archive this kind of functionality?

Comment: Just to be clear, when the flag is true, `brand.locations` should return every record from table `locations`?

Comment: @Magnuss, Yes, you are right!